# Insert list into Excel column

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to insert list to Excel column using xlsxwriter library?

This is my current script:

```
list = ['a','b','c','d']
for letter in list                          
        list.append(letter)
worksheet.write('A1', list)
```

Can anybody could give me a simple insert of list so that I can have my reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
worksheet.write_column('A1', list)
```

docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#write_column

Comment: I already test this but what I mean is to insert a list of list.