# how to convert my two lists columns and rows to excel sheet in python dynamically without hard coding the names

Tags: python, json, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have two lists "columns" and "rows".How to show my two lists in excel sheet in python. actually, am getting those columns and rows from oracle database.so I want to show them in an excel sheet. please help me out.

```
 columns = ['temp', 'var,' 'log'] 
  rows = [['dat2jdhjbcjbd.cdndjs', 45, 'ijh'],['mydatainjjsb.fjdnjc54', 65, null]]
```

how do I show my columns as columns in excel sheet and rows and rows as rows in excel sheet with colors in python dynamically without hardcoding the columns or rows names? My rows are very large.

Comment: Loop your Rows and write it like in this Answer [insert-list-into-excel-column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005851/7414759)

Comment: How can I do that that link doesn't have much information and not clear? can you please provide any code ? @stovfl

Comment: @stovfl after creating the new worksheet were the new worksheet will be stored? were should I give the path for new worksheet what the program will create can you please post the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `pandas`. Probably it's not the best idea to use `pandas` just to write data into excel tables but it makes the process very easy.

(1) Create new excel file:

```
import pandas as pd

# data
columns = ['temp', 'var', 'log']
rows = [
    ['dat2jdhjbcjbd.cdndjs', 45, 'ijh'],
    ['mydatainjjsb.fjdnjc54', 65, None]]

# combine rows and column names into pandas dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

# write data
data.to_excel(
    '1.xlsx',
    sheet_name='new_sheet',
    index=False)
```

(2) Write to existing excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

# data
columns = ['temp', 'var', 'log']
rows = [
    ['dat2jdhjbcjbd.cdndjs', 45, 'ijh'],
    ['mydatainjjsb.fjdnjc54', 65, None]]

# combine rows and column names into pandas dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

filename = '1.xlsx'
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    # open existing excel file
    writer.book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    # add data
    data.to_excel(
        writer,
        sheet_name='new_sheet',
        index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: am getting an error Dataframe constructor not properly called. @Poolka

Comment: in the first solution creating a new excel file where should I give my file location? and why we gave the file name two times? @poolka even am getting the same error  Dataframe constructor not properly called. and how should close the writer in first solution?

Comment: @rohitrocckz (1) If you get `Dataframe constructor not properly called` error then I guess you try to create pandas dataframe from string instead of nested lists or dictionary of lists. (2) File location is the same folder where the script is located. You may use full path instead of just file name. (3) In the second solution filename is used twice because it is used for writer and loader. (4) No need to close writer in both solutions because `data.to_excel(...)` and context manager take care of all service stuff.

Comment: no am asking in the first solution why we wrote twice the file name? what is "1.xlsx" and "new_sheet"? which is file location and which is the file name? @Poolka

Comment: @rohitrocckz `1.xlsx` is a file name. It is a name without path to file so the file is located in the folder where python script is located. `new_sheet` is a name of a sheet in excel table.

Comment: am still getting the same error @Poolka. my data am getting from oracle database and and then am using json.dumps() for gving data to to the pandas dataframe

Comment: @rohitrocckz `json.dumps()` returns a string. That's a problem. To create pandas dataframe you have to deserialize the string. The sample data in the question is a list of lists. It is suitable to create dataframe.

Comment: how can I deserialize ? should I used json.loads?I tried many ways usig xlsxwriter i can able to write my customs columns in excel sheet  but i dont know how to write a rows for those columns can you please help me out.